# log4j2 TcpSocketServer does not replace any "{}" in message

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have a spring boot(v1.5.4) web application which use log4j-2.7 for logging.
It works well when write log message to file or console, but when send message to `TcpSocketServer`, the log server just output the message without the "{}" formatting. for example, for this code:

```
logger.info("Request from [{}] to [{}]", ipInfo, reqPath);
```

The `RollingfileAppender` and `ConsoleAppender` will output:

```
INFO  2017-07-06 16:46:07,929 [127.0.0.1][/senten/align] AuthFilter (http-nio-8180-exec-2) Request from [127.0.0.1] to [/senten/align]
```

But the `SocketAppender` just ouput:

```
INFO  2017-07-06 16:46:07,929 [127.0.0.1][/senten/align] AuthFilter (http-nio-8180-exec-2) Request from [{}] to [{}]
```

This is my config with `SocketAppenders` in log4j.xml

```
<Appenders>
    <Socket name="socket" host="127.0.0.1" port="9898">
        <SerializedLayout />
    </Socket>
    ........
</Appenders>
```

This is my config file `log4j2-socket.xml` for `TcpSocketServer`:

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="default" fileName="Logs/app.log"
            filePattern="Logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%-5p %d [%X{ip}][%X{reqPath}] %c{1} (%t) %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval = "30" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="200 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="default" level="DEBUG" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And, I use this command for start `TcpSocketServer`:

```
java -classpath log4j-core-2.7.jar:log4j-api-2.7.jar:jcommander-1.48.jar org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.server.TcpSocketServer -p 9898 -c log4j2-socket.xml
```

Does anybody know what's going wrong here, and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I file a bug on [JIRA of log4j2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1969). A good guy helps me to resolve this problem.

The solution is update to log4j-2.8.2, and adding this arguments for starting `TcpSocketServer`:

```
--classes java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap --classes java.util.HashMap
```